# Android: Where can I find the code for Google's Music app?

Tags: android

I'm looking for the code for Google's Music app for Android, because I'd like to see what they are doing for the grid that displays your albums. `GridView` is a dog, and I'd like to find a faster Grid for my project.

Comment: Unfortunately, Google's Music application is not open source, at least in the beta stage that it is currently in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're referring to the Music app that sync with Google Music, the source is most likely still in their private Honeycomb branch of Android.  From a user's perspective, it looks a lot like the new Gallery app (i.e. it uses OpenGL), so you might want to take a look at [its source](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Gallery3D.git;a=tree) until the Music app's source is released.

Comment: I found it, thanks to your link: http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=tree